# Theorem 5.3 ([Okounkov-01]) in Borodin and Gorin's lecture note

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, schur-functions

In this lecture note: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3351.pdf, Theorem 5.3(P28):

> Suppose that the $\lambda \in \mathbb{Y}$ is distributed according to the Schur measure $\mathbb{S}_{\rho_1; \rho_2}$. Then $X(\lambda)$ is a determinantal point process on $\mathbb{Z}+1/2$ with correlation kernel $K(i,j)$ defined by the generating series
>
> \begin{align}\label{1}
> (1)\sum_{i, j\in \mathbb{Z}+1/2} K(i,j)v^iw^{-j}=\frac{H(\rho_1; v)H(\rho_2; w^{-1})}{H(\rho_2; v^{-1})H(\rho_1; w)}\sum_{k=1/2, 3/2, 5/2, \dots}(\frac{w}{v})^k
> \end{align}
>
> where $$H(\rho; z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}h_k(\rho)z^k=\exp(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_k(\rho)\frac{z^k}{k})$$

My question is how to rewrite (1) as 
$$K(i,j)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\oint\frac{H(\rho_1; v)H(\rho_2; w^{-1})}{H(\rho_2; v^{-1})H(\rho_1; w)}\frac{\sqrt{vw}}{v-w}\frac{dvdw}{v^{i+1}w^{-j+1}}$$
with integration going over two circles around the origin $|w|=R_1$, $|v|=R_2$ such that $R_1<R_2$ and the functions $H(\rho_1; u), H(\rho_2; u^{-1})$ are holomorphic in the annulus $R_1-\epsilon<|u|<R_2+\epsilon$.

Comment: Did you try to ask the authors?

Comment: Isn't it Cauchy's theorem?